# How to set TClientDataSet field names and displayName

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Delphi 10.3

I'm trying to setup a TClientDataSet to use in my tests, but after adding the fields the Name and DisplayText properties are empty, and the DisplayLabel property has the FieldName property.

```
class function TTestDataSetFactory.CreateTrainingCategoriesDataSet: TDataSet;
var
    DS : TClientDataSet;
    FMaxID : TAggregate;
begin
    DS := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
    DS.Name := 'training_categories';

    with DS.FieldDefs do
    begin
        Add('id', ftInteger, 0, True);
        Add('category', ftString, 50, True);
        Add('description', ftString, 50, False);
    end;


    //Create function adds the aggregate to the DataSet. No more action needed
    FMaxID := TAggregate.Create(DS.Aggregates, DS);
    FMaxID.Expression := 'Max(id)';
    FMaxID.Active := True;
    FMaxID.Visible := True;
    FMaxID.DisplayName := 'MaxID';
    FMaxID.AggregateName := 'max_id';

    DS.CreateDataSet;

  DS.StoreDefs := True;

  DS.Open;

  DS.Fields[0].Name := 'id';
  DS.Fields[1].Name := 'category';
  DS.Fields[2].Name := 'description';

  DS.Fields[0].DisplayLabel := 'ID';
  DS.Fields[1].DisplayLabel := 'Category';
  DS.Fields[2].DisplayLabel := 'Description';

    DS.AggregatesActive := True;
    DS.Close;
    //Setup AutoInc, performed in AfterInsert event, with ID field (0)
    DS.AfterInsert := IncIdAtIndex0;
    Result := DS;
end;
```

Just a quick test:

```
procedure TTestDataSetFactoryTest.CreateTrainingCategoriesDataSet_ReturnsCorrectDataSet;
var
  DS : TDataset;
begin
  DS := TTestDataSetFactory.CreateTrainingCategoriesDataSet;
  DS.Open;

  CodeSite.Send( Format('Field 0 DisplayLabel = %s',[DS.Fields[0].DisplayLabel]) );
  CodeSite.Send( Format('Field 0 Name = %s',[DS.Fields[0].Name]) );
  CodeSite.Send( Format('Field 0 DisplayText = %s',[DS.Fields[0].DisplayText]) );

  Assert.AreEqual(3, DS.Fields.Count);

  Assert.AreEqual('id', DS.Fields[0].Name);
  Assert.AreEqual('category', DS.Fields[1].Name);
  Assert.AreEqual('description', DS.Fields[2].Name);

  Assert.AreEqual('ID', DS.Fields[0].DisplayName);
  Assert.AreEqual('Category', DS.Fields[1].DisplayName);
  Assert.AreEqual('Description', DS.Fields[2].DisplayName);

  DS.Close;
end;
```

The  Assert.AreEqual(3, DS.Fields.Count); passes but all Name and DisplayText properties fail.

Field[0] logs this

Field 0 DisplayLabel = id

Field 0 Name =

Field 0 DisplayText =

Adding the field property assignments into the test everything passes, so the fields are present.

Does anyone know why the field properties are not set in the Dataset creation? The fields are there. The assigned name of the DataSet is fine also.

Thanks in advance

Gary

Comment: After `Close()` DS fields are destroyed. You must define `DisplayLabel` after `Open()`.

Comment: Fwiw, DS.AfterInsert is not the right way to handle autoinc behaviour - the OnNewRecord event is the correct place to deal with this.

Comment: Also, afaik there has never been any need for the indirection of creating FieldDefs to in turn create TFields.  You can create TFields directly in code instead, and giving them a TPersistent Owner makes them persistent too.  Simples.

Comment: MartynA  Thanks for the OnNewRecord tip. I new that was going to give me trouble when I wanted to actually use the AfterInsert in my program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign lcPersistent to the LifeCycle property like this:

```
DS.Fields[0].LifeCycle    := lcPersistent;
DS.Fields[0].Name         := 'id';
DS.Fields[0].DisplayLabel := 'ID';
```

And of course do the same with all fields.

Warning: The field property *name* must be unique because it is used as component name which must be unique. You should probably construct it with dataset name combined.

Comment: fpiette, That's exactly what I was looking for!  I tried DS.StoreDefs := True; but obviously that doesn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

FPiette has given you a fine and up-to-date (using the fairly recent TField.LifeCycle) answer to creating
TFields from TFieldDefs.  I just want to mention an alternative which does not require the use of TFieldDefs.

As a TDataSet is opened, its BindFields method is called, which "connects" its collection of TFields with the
field buffers which store the records read from the datafile.  **If** the fields do not already exist, they are
created at the time, but if they do, there is not need to create them.

What this means is that very simple code like the following is all that is required to create and use
the DataSet's TFields.  The simple step of creating the TFields with a persistent owner - in the example, the form -
ensures that they last for the lifetime of their Owner.  That's how persistent TFields created in the IDE using the Fields editor (invoked by double-clicked the DataSet's icon) work.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AField : TField;
begin
  AField := TIntegerField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldKind := fkData;
  AField.FieldName := 'ID';
  AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

  AField := TStringField.Create(Self);
  AField.FieldKind := fkData;
  AField.FieldName := 'AValue';
  AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;

  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([1, 'One']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([2, 'Two']);
  ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([3, 'Three']);
end;
```

Comment: MartynA, Thank you, but I am using the Dataset to mimic the real MYSQL table in tests, so there is no persistent owner, no forms just a reference

Comment: Sure, but there is nothing to stop the dataset itself being the Owner.

Comment: Good to know! I'll give that a try as well.

Comment: I have 10 tables I use at different times and the way I was doing it worked fine until I needed the above mentioned properties. So going back and refactoring I find Martyn's example the easiest, even though FPiette gave the exact fix to my way. I'm going to leave both in the code so I can refer back to them another time.